# InstallReferrelReceiver is not called sometimes app is downloaded from PlayStore

Tags: android

Am working with two apps, In ***A App*** on clicking button, i hit the playstore link of ***B App*** and send data in playstore url and when app is installed, i get parameters from "referrel"

I used InstallReferrelReciever in manifest of  **B app** as like:

```
    <receiver android:name=".data.AppInstallReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

so here i get issue on some devices like Redmi and Oppo  InstallReferrelReceiver is not called sometime but that works fine on Samsung devices.